# Is there any way to obfuscate just real code, and not ofuscate Libraries?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I'm having some issues while obfuscating code with ProGuard. Basically GSON library is giving me a pain.

So I thought about obfuscating just com.mypackages.* and do not obfuscate used libraries.

Is it possible?

How is this called? I'm kinda lost at obfuscation atm, and I couldn't find any examples about that.

Any tips are soo appreciated.

Edit:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$EnumTypeAdapter.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$26.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Unknown Source)
```

After adding

```
-keepnames class com.google.gson.** {*;}
```

Edit2:
I kept trying new things like:

```
-keep class com.google.**
-keepnames class com.google.** {*;}
-keepnames enum com.google.** {*;}
-keepnames interface com.google.** {*;}
```

And no luck so far.

Comment: Yes, it's possible though you'd have to research the details.  But note that every time you invoke something by a clear name, especially if it is something like a well known library or platform API, you leave a big hint as to what your code is up to.

Comment: Here's the ProGuard manual for reference: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/introduction.html

Comment: @Sergi Did any sollution work mate?

Comment: @Radu not really... I've tried everything, and I'm still facing this issue. I gave up months ago, this is something I want to try sometime soon again, but for now, code is totally clean in production :D

Comment: @kabuko What worked for me is this: -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
} changed to: -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    *;
}

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán Hi Sergi, you can look at my comment above, it worked!!

Comment: @Radu I'm currently working on other higher priority tasks :P So I can't really check it right now, asap I will and text you back :)

Comment: @Radu solution worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of to keep the GSON library from being obfuscated is to add something like this to your ProGuard config:

```
-keepnames com.google.gson.** {*;}
```

Comment: this keepnames misses something.

Answer (score 0):

With `-keepnames`, ProGuard's obfuscation step preserves the names of the specified classes, fields, and methods. ProGuard's shrinking step and optimization step may still remove the classes, fields, and methods themselves, if they appear unused. You want to use the more common `-keep` option:

```
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
```

This line keeps the matching classes, fields, and methods, with their original names. It also matches interface classes and enum classes.

See the ProGuard manual > Usage > [Overview of Keep Options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoverview)

Comment: Hi, this is my proguard config: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/attachmentText?id=561&aid=5610000000&name=proguard-project.txt&token=61GhJ8MHutMdJdwJJOxz6p3ut2k%3A1392821570369 however, the same error occurs

Answer (score 0):

I too spent time struggling with this. In my case, it was **not** on the Gson side of things, but the enum that it was trying to deserialize (MyClass.MyEnum in this case). I used this:

```
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep enum com.abc.MyClass$MyEnum { *; }
```

Adding the second line above caused my code to make it past the problem and the application was functional again. Hope this helps!